# big-o notation - prove that $3n^2 - 1$ is or is not $O(n^2)$

Tags: asymptotics

Is $3n^2 - 1$ is or is not $O(n^2)$?

I tried to solve it by adding the constants to get $c: 3 + 1 = 4; c = 4$.

If $n \geq n_0$ and $n_0$ is $1$, $3n^2 - 1 \leq 4n^2$. However, to disprove it, I tried to substitute zero to the equation:

$3n^2 - 1 \leq cn^2$

$\implies 3(0^2) - 1 \leq 4(0^2)$

$\implies 0 - 1 \leq 0$

$\implies -1 \leq 0$

So it seems that for values lower than 1, it is still true. Can someone help me to explain this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint : Find out the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3n^2-1}{n^2}$$

Comment: You are correct that $3n^2 - 1$ is $O(n^2)$ by the method you've showed. I am not sure what you think the rest of the argument tries to show. Indeed $3n^2 - 1 < 4n^2$ for ALL n.

Comment: @naslundx, I thought it is `O(n^2)` only for all `n >= 1`? If that's the case, then for all `n < 1`, it should not be `O(n^2)`? So if I substitute any value starting from 1 and above, `3n^2 - 1` is indeed <= `4n^2`. However, if I substitute zero, I still get `<=`.

Comment: Checking  what happens for $n=0$ is meaningless: the notation $O(n^2)$ is about what happens when $n$ gets larger and larger.

Comment: @Bernard, just to clarify, in case `n >=10`, do you mean that it will also be meaningless to check values less than `10`?

Comment: I suppose you mean $n_{\color{red}0}\ge 10$? Yes. Anyway, in general, the problem is not to find the best possible value for $n_0$, but to know there exists one.

Comment: Yes @Bernard, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n) = O(n^2)$ if there **exist** two positive $n_0,c$ such that 
$$0 \le f(n) \le cn^2$$ 
for all $n \ge n_0$. Therefore, $3n^2-1=O(n^2)$ since one can choose $n_0 = 2, c=3$.